# Loop, For, Cursores PL/SQL (Duvida)

Tags: sql, oracle, loop, for, cursor

Bom dia Galera,
a minha duvida é a seguinte, minha tabela está assim atualmente:

```
Nome    Idade   ID
João    5       
Lucas   5   
João    2   
Lucas   1
```

Eu desejo que ela fique assim:

```
Nome    Idade   ID
João    2       1
João    5       2
Lucas   1       1
Lucas   5       2
```

Só que meu cursor está deixando a tabela assim:

```
Nome    Idade   ID
João    2       1
João    5       1
Lucas   1       2
Lucas   5       2
```

alguém pode me ajudar, esse é meu cursor:

```
Declare
  v_contador  number := 0;
  v_min_idade number := 0;

  cursor c_i is
    select t.*, rowid from teste_matheus t order by nome, idade asc;

begin
  for i in c_i loop

    select min(idade)
      into v_min_idade
      from teste_matheus
     where id is null
       and nome = i.nome;

    if i.idade = v_min_idade and i.id is null then
       v_contador := v_contador + 1; 

      update teste_matheus t
         set id = v_contador
       WHERE id is null
         and nome = i.nome;

     END IF;
    END LOOP;
   END;
```

Obrigado! ^^

Comment: CONSEGUI!!! Caso alguém passe pelo mesmo perrengue, está aí.

Declare
  V_ant       varchar2(100) := 'X';
  v_contador  number := 0;
  v_min_idade number := 0;

  cursor c_i is
    select t.*, rowid from teste_matheus t order by nome, idade asc;

begin
  for i in c_i loop
    if v_ant <> i.nome then
      v_contador := 1;
      v_ant      := i.nome;
    else
      v_contador := v_contador + 1;
    end if;
  
    update teste_matheus t set id = v_contador WHERE t.rowid = i.rowid;
    commit;
  END LOOP;
END;